# Total noob, how do I make something into jelly

Tags: physics

I have an Animal Crossing model that I've rigged for some small animation, but I would like to render it falling out of the sky, hitting the ground and jiggling on impact. The tutorial's I've found have been kinda old or not very helpful, and I'm not a huge fan of youtube tutorials. Any help? Assume I know nothing I barely figured out how to rig it with bones.

Comment: Hello, are you also trying to animate it with the armature during the sequence?

Comment: Why rig it?  Give it soft body physics with no goal (goal default 0.0).  Set other parameters, like push + pull should probably be more like 0.9, but it depends on your vert density.  It'll fall and jiggle....

Comment: @Nathan: maybe the user wants to control that jiggling or needs specific moves.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth yes, maybe they do, but if they do, exactly what they want to be able to control, as opposed to leave up to physics, affects the decisions they should make about their physics.  We need to know from them what their goals are to answer the question best.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure how much info was really needed, I rigged it because I want to do some minor animations with it but I'm going to use the unrigged model to have a scene where it just falls out of the sky and hits the ground and jiggles around. Again I don't know nothin about nothin I started using blender a few days ago lol I'll try your suggestion Nathan!